# Assigning values to sparse matrix in R -each row at different column

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

```
nr <- 3    
nc <- 4    
rxc <- nr*nc
```

1)

```
m2 <- Matrix(0, nrow = nc, ncol = rxc, sparse = TRUE)  
for (r in 1:nrow(m2)) {   
 m2[r,seq(r,rxc,nc)] <- 1    
}
```

2)

```
m2 <- Matrix(0, nrow = nc, ncol = rxc, sparse = TRUE) 
for (r in 1:nrow(m2)) {
  m2[cbind(rep(r,(rxc/nc)),seq(r,rxc,nc))] <- 1
}
```

Desired output

```
[1,] 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . . .   
[2,] . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . .   
[3,] . . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 .  
[4,] . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1
```

Both this method works for small matrices. My matrix will have 120 million columns and 12 rows. Is there any better way do it in R ?

Answer (score 0):

After you set the elements with your method, it's easy to spot a pattern of the `1` elements. For instance, see this:

```
which(m2==1)
#[1]  1  6 11 16 17 22 27 32 33 38 43 48
```

Or better:

```
diff(which(m2==1)) 
#[1] 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 1 5 5 5
```

This pattern is pretty easy to reproduce:

```
m2<-Matrix(0, nrow = nc, ncol = rxc, sparse = TRUE)
indices<-c(1,cumsum(rep(c(rep(nrow(m2)+1,nrow(m2)-1),1),ncol(m2)/nrow(m2)))+1)
indices<-indices[1:(length(indices)-1)]
m2[indices]<-1
```